# How to use Where before Left Join MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that have a structure like this. First the users table:

```
id  |  email  | password
 1    'email'    'pass'
 2    'new2'      'pass'
```

and the report table:

```
user_id  | field  | text
  1         4       Tom
```

How can I return back the the `email` and `password` values even if the user doesn't have a match in the `report` table? This is what I have so far.

```
    select a.email, a.password, b.text from users a
    left join data b
    on a.id = b.user_id
    and b.field = 4
    and a.id = 2;
```

Desired output to get info on user with ID of 2:

```
email  |   password   | text
'new2'     'pass'
```

I currently don't get anything back with what i've tried so far

Comment: Where's your from clause in your example SQL?  By moving the where  criteria to the join, you should get all records from A and only those that match from B.  `FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on the *first* table in a `left join` go in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the *second* table go in the `on` clause:

```
select u.email, u.password, d.text
from users u left join
     data d
     on u.id = d.user_id and d.field = 4
where a.id = 2;
```

The rule might seem arbitrary at first.  However, it is not.  The `left join` returns all rows in the first table *regardless* of whether the `on` clause evaluates to true.  Hence, a filtering condition on the first table does not filter out any rows.  The `where` clause does this filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      u.email
    , u.password
    , r.text

FROM 
    users AS u

    LEFT JOIN report AS r
        ON r.user_id = u.id

WHERE 
    u.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you pasted your query into your question correctly, but if I understand what you're after, this should work:

```
SELECT a.email, a.password, b.text
FROM   users a
LEFT JOIN report b ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE  a.id = 2
```

It isn't clear why you are trying to check for `b.field`, but if you need to do so, then go ahead an add it to the `LEFT JOIN`.  In general, put conditions in the `LEFT JOIN ... ON` when you still want rows to be returned, and put conditions in the `WHERE` clause when they rows should not be returned if the condition isn't met.